# Базовый класс Array и производные классы SortArray и XorArray

Tags: c++, массивы, ооп, virtual

Помогите закончить программу пожалуйста. Необходимо создать базовый класс Array с виртуальными методами сложения и поэлементной обработки foreach() и производные от него классы Sort Array и XorArray. В SortArray операцию сложения реализовать как пересечение множеств, а поэлементную обработку извлечением корня каждого элемента массива. В XorArray сложение как исключающее или, а поэлементная обработка - сортировка массива. Я уже задал foreach() для обоих классов (для второго не уверен, что верно). Не могу реализовать сложение, компилятор жалуется ещё в базовом классе. Ниже привиден код. Ошибка в SortArray::add - error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Array' (не единственная)

```
#ifndef ARRAY
#define ARRAY
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

class Array{
public:
    double *arr;
    size_t sz;

public:
    Array () {
        arr = nullptr;
        sz = 0;
    }
    Array (size_t _sz){
        arr = new double[_sz];
        sz = _sz;
    }
    Array (double *a, size_t s){
        sz = s;
        arr = new double [s];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            arr[i] = a[i];
    }
    Array (const Array& other){
        sz = other.sz;
        arr = new double [sz];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            arr[i] = other.arr[i];
    }
    virtual ~Array (){
        delete [] arr;
    }
    void print() const {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
            cout << setw(6) << setiosflags(ios::showpoint) << setprecision(3) << arr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }
    double& operator[](size_t i) {
        if(i < 0 || i >= sz) throw out_of_range("Exit for size");
        else return arr[i];
    }
    size_t resize(size_t newsz) {
        if(newsz < sz)
            return sz;
        else {
            double *newarr = new double [newsz];
            for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
                newarr[i] = arr[i];
            for(size_t i = sz; i < newsz; ++i)
                newarr[i] = 0;
            sz = newsz;
            delete [] arr;
            arr = newarr;
            return newsz;
        }
    }
   size_t size() const {
        return sz;
   }

    virtual Array& add (Array&) const = 0;
    virtual void foreach () = 0;
};
#endif // ARRAY



//SortArray методы
    SortArray& add (const Array&other){
        Array *temp;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
            temp [i] = arr[i];
        for(size_t j = sz; j < other.sz; j++)
            temp [j] = other.arr[j - sz];
        return temp;
    }

    void foreach(){
    double temp;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz - 1; i++) {
         for (size_t j = 0; j < sz - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
 }

// XorArray методы

    XorArray& add (const Array &x){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < arr; i++)
            x.arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[i];
    }

    void foreach(){
        double *newarr = new double[sz];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
            arr[i] = sqrt(newarr[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Копирующий конструктор - сделали, а оператор присваивания - забыли. Это не ошибка, но в реальной программе таким классом нормально пользоваться не получится... Плюс, в дополнение к текущему варианту `operator[]` хорошо бы добавить `const` перегрузку, иначе как доставать числа из константных массивов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во первых нет нужды делать базовый класс абстрактным, обьявляя в нем две чисто_виртуальные функции.  Вы должны их определять, чтобы базовый класс по своему выполнял и имели бы возможность создавать обьекты базового класса.

```
virtual Array&  Array::add (Array&) const;
virtual void Array::foreach ();
```

Во вторых вы функцию определяете с помощью битовой операции, но битовую операцию вы пытаетесь выполнять на переменных типа `double`, что невозможно. Правда, я не ясно понел условие задачи, но можно сделать, например, так:

```
// XorArray методы
// для начала сделайте члены класса защищенными, а не закрытыми
Array& XorArray::add(const Array &x) override
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
         double d1 = arr[i], d2 = x.arr[i];
         int x1 = d1, x2 = d2;
         arr[i] = (x1 ^ x2) + (d1 - x1) + (d2 - x2);
    }
    return *this;                     
}
```

И еще вы определяете копирующий конструктор неправильно: Нужно уничтожать старый массив, если размер копируемого обьекта различается, и после создавать новый, в обратном случаи просто присвоения:

```
Array (const Array& other){
    if ( sz != other.sz) {
        delete arr;
        sz = other.sz; 
        arr = new double [sz];            
    }               
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        arr[i] = other.arr[i];
}
```

Не смотрел есть ли еще другие ошибки?.. Но нужно также определять оператор присваивания

Comment: Совет: не используйте индентификатор  foreach, придумайте другое имя

Comment: Foreach у меня по заданию нужно назвать) а ошибки есть, по крайней мере та, которую указал allocate есть в add'ах обоих классов. Мне их нужно хорошо прописать, а я с синтаксисом плохо ознакомлен. Ещё вопрос, у меня без типа `double` не получится, т.к. нужен корень квадратный в XorArray.

Comment: А я не советовал не использовать double. Просто нужно не пытаться выполнять битовые операции над ними.  x.arr[i] = arr[i] ^ arr[i];  вот это зачем? Просто берите суммируйте

Comment: Опять же, в задании указано, что нужно сложить массивы как Исключающее ИЛИ, а то что я написал, это набросок для размышления, как же правильно его реализовать

Comment: Григорий Волжин, читайте обновленный ответ

Answer (score 0):

Вы неправильно объявили методы наследников. Сигнатуры виртуальных методов должны совпадать с сигнатурами базового класса, т.е. объявление наследника должно быть примерно таким:

```
class SortArray: public Array{
  ...
  Array& add (Array&) const override; 
  void foreach() override;
  ...
};
```

Чтобы не допускать таких ошибок, используйте `override` в наследниках - при этом в случае ошибки компилятор прямо скажет, что в базовом классе нет виртуального метода с такой сигнатурой.

Comment: Можно попросить вас скинуть ссылку на хороший источник, где все будет расписано по полочкам. Я не понимаю, как должны наследники принимать значения от базового класса и никак не могу разобраться, уже пару учебников перечитал, но с их примерами...